# Does conditional probability imply causation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

When writing the conditional probability $P(A|B)$, which is interpreted to be that given $B$ what is the probability of observing $A$, can one also claim that this says the probability of observing $A$ being caused by $B$, i.e., is there a causal connection between $B$ and $A$?

Thanks!

Comment: Check out Pearl's do-calculus. The do operator can answer your question: $B$ causes $A$ if $P(A|\operatorname{do}(B))>P(A).$

Answer (score 2):

Consider $B$ being "a person was breathing this morning" and $A$ being "that person is dead".

$P(A \mid B)$ is the probability that the person died having been breathing earlier in the day. This is likely to be a small but nonzero number, approximately equal to the probability that a random person dies on any given day.

Nonetheless, you'd probably not want to conclude that breathing leads to death in any meaningful way. (Indeed, a better conclusion is that *not* breathing leads to death!)

Comment: Hi. But shouldn't $A$ and $B$ strictly be random events?

Comment: "you'd probably not want to conclude that breathing leads to death in any meaningful way" And yet, oxygen is literally killing all of us, through oxidative stress.

Comment: @ThomasMoore: I don't understand your question, so I won't attempt to answer. I know what a probability space is, and what an event in such a space is, but I don't know what a "random event" might be. Perhaps you can enlighten me.

Answer (score 1):

No, not at all. Consider, $B$="the flagpole's shadow is very short", $A$="the sun is high in the sky".

$P(A \mid B)$ could be very high, but $B$ does not cause $A$.

Here's another example that I believe is due to R.A. Fisher (but I may be wrong about that). Let $A$="you get lung cancer" and $B$="you smoke heavily". We know that $P(A \mid B)$ is quite high and are quite confident that $B$ in fact causes $A$.

But the causal claim doesn't follow from the high conditional probability alone. For suppose that $A$ and $B$ are causally unrelated but that $C$ is a *common cause* of both $A$ and $B$. For example, $C$ could be "you have a gene that causes both a strong desire to smoke and lung cancer." Then, given $B$, it's highly likely (we suppose) that $C$ is operative, and hence that $A$ occurs. So $P(A \mid B)$ is high. But, by assumption, $B$ and $A$ do not influence each other casually.

Comment: Hi. But, shouldn't $A$ and $B$ strictly be random events?

Comment: @ThomasMoore Could you explain what you mean by "random event"?

Answer (score 0):

Good news - there's a positive answer to a perhaps not totally unrelated question below.

We know the definition of $P(A|B)$. For this to imply anything about causation you need to first give a precise mathematical definition of "$B$ caused $A$"...

Now, material implication is not causation (in fact the fact that material implication says nothing about causation is why it sometimes seems somehow "wrong" to  beginners). But it does have a nice simple precise definition.

One might plausibly define the event $B\implies A$ by $$B\implies A=\{\omega\in\Omega:\omega\in B\implies\omega\in A\}.$$

(In other words: That definition says that $B\implies A$ is the set of $\omega$ such that $\omega\in A$ or $\omega\notin B$, or $$(B\implies A)=A\cup(\Omega\setminus B).)$$

And then it turns out that if $P(A|B)$ is large it *does* follow that $P(B\implies A)$ is large.

Note that the complement of $B\implies A$ is just $B\setminus A$. So
$$1-P(B\implies A)=(P(B)-P(A\cap  B))=P(B)(1-P(A|B))\le1-P(A|B).$$Proving

> > **Ullrich's Astounding Theorem** If $P(B)>0$ then $P(B\implies A)\ge P(A|B)$.

Comment: You should indicate much more clearly that the composition of events $(B\implies A)$ that you introduce in the post, is of your own invention and absolutely not standard. Then, mentioning more clearly the fact that $$\Omega\setminus(B\implies A)=B\setminus A$$ might help relating it to standard notions.

Comment: Hmmm... By the way, re-reading once more your answer, I am ready to bet that the OP will not find easy to grasp the definition of $(B\implies A)$...

Comment: @Did Perhaps. (i) I did say "One might plausibly define..." which it seems to me makes it clear that this is not a standard definition. (ii) I decided later it's not as wacky as I thought at first, since "$\implies$" is a Boolean operator annd a $\sigma$-algebra is among other things a Boolean algebra; from that point of view $A\implies B$ should be just "$B$ or not $A$", or $B\cup(\Omega\setminus A)$, which is exactly what I said it was.